# Copying Schemas & Tables from Redshift to RDS

Tags: amazon-redshift, amazon-rds

Is it possible to copy all `schemas` and `tables` in addition to any permissions from a Redshift database to a RDS database?

> Note: Im connecting to both databases through DBeaver, the Redshift
>   database is using a Redshift driver and the RDS database is using a
>   postgreSQL driver.

Comment: how far do you get with a pg_dump from redshift? how much of what you need is successfully pg_restore(d) to RDS postgres?

Answer (score 0):

First, you can create the `schema` from your database with the following [script](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/blob/master/src/AdminViews/v_generate_schema_ddl.sql) from the [redshift-utils](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils). Afterward you can [`unload`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html) the needed table from redshift to S3 from where you can import it to your destination database.

OR

You can use AWS services like [data-pipeline](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/data-pipeline/index.html).